# Evaluate $(\sqrt{3}+i)^{14}+(\sqrt{3}-i)^{14}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $(\sqrt{3}+i)^{14}+(\sqrt{3}-i)^{14}$

I tried by using the De'moivers theorem but I didn't get proper value I get a mess value 4..but I am not sure about the answer can anyone please tell me

Comment: Hint:  Try smaller exponents, see if you can spot a pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that $z=\sqrt 3+i=2e^{i\pi/6}$. Then $z^{14}=2^{14}e^{14i\pi/6}=2^{14}e^{i\pi/3}$.

Now, $z^{14}+\bar z^{14}=2\Re(z^{14})=2\cdot2^{14}\cos(\pi/3)=2^{14}=16384$

Comment: If you are in any competetive exam calc is not allowed so how would you find the value $2^{14}$

Comment: Well, I made it by hand, it's not so big.

Comment: ohh ok ok ..Nice

Answer (score 2):

For a different sort of computation:

Let $$a_n=(\sqrt 3 +i)^{2n}+(\sqrt 3-i)^{2n}$$

We note that $\alpha = (\sqrt 3+i)$ satisfies $x^4-4x^2+16$ from which it follows that $\alpha^2$ satisfies $x^2-4x+16$.   It follows that we have the recursion $$a_n=4a_{n-1}-16a_{n-2}$$  As it is clear that $$a_0=2\quad \& \quad a_1=4$$  we can easily compute $$a_7=16384$$

Side note:  somewhat curiously, it is not obvious from this point of view that $a_n$ is always a power of $2$, at least up to sign.  Indeed, the relevant powers of $2$, namely $\{1,2,4,7,8,10,13,\cdots\}$, follow a (slightly) unexpected pattern.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to factorise by $2^{14}$ :).

$(\sqrt{3} + i)^{14} + (\sqrt{3} - i)^{14} = 2^{14}(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \dfrac{i}{2})^{14} + 2^{14}(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \dfrac{i}{2})^{14} = 2^{14}\left((\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \dfrac{i}{2})^{14} + (\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \dfrac{i}{2})^{14}\right)$

Now, use the fact that: $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \dfrac{i}{2} = \cos(\pi/6) + i\sin(\pi/6) = \exp(i\pi/6)$.

And similarly: $\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \dfrac{i}{2} = \cos(-\pi/6) + i\sin(-\pi/6) = \exp(-i\pi/6)$.

I think you'll be able to finish from there, by using De Moivre's theorem :)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
(\sqrt{3} + i)^{14} = ((\sqrt{3} + i)^2)^7
$$
Also, $ (\sqrt{3} + i)^2 = 2 + i 2\sqrt{3} = 2 (2 e^{j\theta}) = 4 e^{j\theta}$, where $ \theta = \pi / 3 $.
Similarly, for the second term we have that $ (\sqrt{3} - i)^2 = 4 e^{-j\theta} $.
You problem reduces to finding

$$ 
M = 4^7 \cdot e^{j 7\theta} + 4^7 \cdot e^{-j 7\theta}  
= 4^7 \cdot 2 \cdot (\frac{e^{j 7\theta} + e^{-j 7\theta}}{2})  
= 4^7 \cdot \cos(7\theta)
= 4^7 \cdot 1
= 16384
$$